# SSIS Loop Stopping on Failure

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that downloads a group of CSV files from an FTP site and once the files are local, it loops through the files and imports them into a SQL table.
I programmed it in a way that if one of the files fails to import into the SQL files it sets a variable (to deal with the failure later on for notifications, etc), but keeps on looping through the rest of the local CSV files.
Or so I thought...
I just realized that when one of the import to SQL fails, the loop stops.

Here's the loop
[image]

And here is the import data flow that is "called" from the loop.

[image]

So I guess my question is how to I keep the loop going???

Thanks!

Comment: Increase the max errors property of the loop to the number of possible loop cycles.

Comment: It makes sense, but why would the loop fail if I took care of the failure path and linking to another tasks (a script) in which I purposely succeed it?

Comment: Doesn't matter. It works for me. I don't know how many files will be in there, especially if the link to the ftp site is down for a few days so I'll just set MaximumErrorCount to 0. Add your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the loop terminating, you need to set the max errors property of the loop to the maximum expected number of loop cycles.

Normally, I advocate coding to handle exceptions gracefully so that actual errors can still be trapped, but I can't think of a way to do that with a data flow task that doesn't involve a fair amount of additional hassle.

You may want to use a .net script to verify that the number of files and rows in the file system matches the number actually loaded into SQL server.